# How to get partition name of a row in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with hash partitioning. I need to find out that in which partition a specific row placed. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.
This is the query:

`EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM table WHERE expression`